# diff tool - check if same line exists in both files

Tags: xml, diff, compare

I am looking for a diff tool that will allow me to compare two files, regardless of the order of lines. So if one file has line 54 saying XXXXXXX, I will see that it exists in the other file even if its line 66. It seems that KDiff3 is not noticing it... I'm trying to compare xml files.

Comment: You can [place manual sync marks][1] with KDiff3, does that solve your problem?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067839/context-aware-merge/5117210#5117210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. XML Notepad 2007 has a built in diff tool and even if lines are in different order it will properly compare the files.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/). I've found this to work well for refactored content.

Comment: It does not detect same lines if they are in a different place :(

Comment: I'm not sure if any current tool can give you the granularity you want. I've read that Git's `blame` feature allows you to better track block moves, but I haven't used it so can only point you to it as a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this does exactly what you are looking for but Pretty Diff at http://prettydiff.com/ is an algorithmic diff tool supporting XML.  It minifies code samples to remove comments and then beautifies the code samples to normalize white space and indentation.  You can try it out online by pasting code samples in or using the tests provided on the samples page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but something I did was to create two columns in a spreadsheet, then added a third column with a VLOOKUP that detects if the line is 1) new or, 2) deleted