# Is it possible to avoid 'offset issues' when resolving merge conflicts?

Tags: git, merge, conflict, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Suppose you have 2 methods in a file:

```
BASE
----
m1
m2
```

Now both developers modify the methods *slightly*. But one developer adds a new method at the top of the file

```
MINE    |  THIERS
--------+--------
m1'     |   m0
m2'     |   m1''
        |   m2''
```

I want to see a comparison of `m1'` vrs `m1''` and `m2'` vrs `m2''`. The tools that I have been using (FileMerge & P4Merge) often seem to show  `m1'` vrs  `m0` and `m2'` vrs `m1''`.

Without seeing like for like its very hard to tell what has been changed.  Is there a tool or a strategy to make these kinds of merges less painful?

Comment: Git has a "patience diff" algorithm that spends more CPU time to attempt to produce a more useful result.  The newer git variants have a "histogram" variant of this.  Whether they will actually help, I don't know, but they are worth trying.  See `-X patience`, `-X diff-algorithm=...` (when used with `git merge`).

Answer (score 1):

In [Araxis Merge](http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.en), you can add [synchronization links](http://www.araxis.com/merge/documentation-windows/synchronization-links.en) between the two or three files being compared. You add a synchronization link between similar parts of the two files - in your example, you'd perhaps create synchronization links between `m1'` and `m1''`, and `m2'` and `m2''`. Those parts of the files would then be compared against each other, instead of the situation you're currently experiencing - `m1'` being compared against `m0`, to which it has no relationship.

Answer (score 1):

In [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), you can add [synchronization links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117210/23118) between the two or three files being compared (probably very similar to Araxis Merge, although I have never tried it). I cannot recommend KDiff3 highly enough, it is an excellent free (GPL) tool that I use almost daily.