# Merge conflict in git parallel branches

Tags: git, merge, parallel-processing, branch

I'm trying to achieve a scenario in git.
I started with a text file with four lines and then made 4 branches each changes one line in the text file and they work in parallel with each one having a copy of the original file as in the picture.
[image]
When I merge the branches, the first merge always succeeds like this:

```
Updating 0b18c93..274ba8c
Fast-forward
 t.txt | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

but I get merge conflicts in the later merges.

```
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Is there a method to achieve this scenario without getting merge conflicts?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - That's incorrect.  "They didn't change line X" is not a conflict with "we did change line X".  The reason these conflict is that "we" changed a line "too close to" the line "they" changed, and git interprets that as differing changes to the same hunk of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995390/1256452) (which is correct and I've upvoted it): You need to realize that your first merge isn't a merge at all.  That's why Git says:

> ```
> Fast-forward
> ```

The merge process, as jthill said:

> finds (and in some cases Git's merge will actually construct) the common base and compares diffs from that base to each branch tip. Any differences in overlapping ranges constitutes a conflict.

But for the first `git merge` command, the common base *is* one of the branch tips.

#### The first one is free

Let's see how that is:

```
$ mkdir tt; cd tt; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ cat << END > myfile.txt
01
02
03
04
END
$ git add myfile.txt
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) b1a22ca] initial
 1 file changed, 4 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 myfile.txt
$ git checkout -b br1
Switched to a new branch 'br1'
$ ed myfile.txt
12
1s/$/ one/
w
16
q
$ git add myfile.txt
$ git commit -m 'change line 1'
[br1 b31f04a] change line 1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* b31f04a (HEAD -> br1) change line 1
* b1a22ca (master) initial
```

(If you're not familiar with the `ed` editor, it is a rather minimal text-only editor that prints the number of bytes in the input file when started up, and has commands of the form: *line-number(s)* *operation*.  So `1s/$/ one/` means "replace the end of line 1 with  `one`.  The `w` command writes the file back, and `q` quits the editor.)

We do not have to create the extra branches `br2`, `br3`, and `br4` yet, but let's go ahead and do that anyway, creating them so that they point to commit `b1a22ca`:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git branch br2 && git branch br3 && git branch br4
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* b31f04a (br1) change line 1
* b1a22ca (HEAD -> master, br4, br3, br2) initial
```

At this point, we have a graph that looks like this, if we draw it horizontally instead of vertically the way Git does:

```
b1a22ca   <-- master (HEAD), br2, br3, br4
    \
   b31f04a   <-- br1
```

That is, the branch name `br1` indicates that its tip commit is `b31f04a`, while the branch names `master` and the other three `br`s all indicate that *their* tip commit is `b1a22ca`.

Let's go ahead and create a new commit on br2 now:

```
$ git checkout br2
Switched to branch 'br2'
$ ed myfile.txt
12
1,$p
01
02
03
04
2s/$/ two/
w
16
q
$ git add myfile.txt 
$ git commit -m 'change line 2'
[br2 805ea58] change line 2
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

and see how `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` draws it:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 805ea58 (HEAD -> br2) change line 2
| * b31f04a (br1) change line 1
|/  
* b1a22ca (master, br4, br3) initial
```

In my preferred horizontal graph drawing—where newer commits are to the right, rather than above—we have:

```
   805ea58   <-- br2 (HEAD)
    /
b1a22ca   <-- master, br3, br4
    \
   b31f04a   <-- br1
```

If we now run `git checkout master && git merge br1`, Git will locate, for us, the *merge base* commit.  That's the "nearest" commit that's on *both* branches `br1` *and* `master`.

***Note that at this point, commit `b31f04a` is only on `br1`, and commit `805ea58` is only on `br2`, but commit `b1a22ca` is on every branch.***  This is a key thing in Git: branches "contain" commits, and any given commit can be on many branches simultaneously.

Having found the merge base, Git now must combine two sets of changes:

- the changes from the merge base `b1a22ca` to the tip of `master`: `b1a22ca`;
- the changes from the merge base `b1a22ca` to the tip of `br1`: `b31f04a`.

But `b1a22ca` *is* `b1a22ca`.  There cannot possibly be any changes here!

What Git does by default for this case is to do a *fast forward*.  A fast forward is not a merge at all!  It just amounts to switching to the other commit, in this case `b31f04a`, and dragging the name `master` forward to point to that commit:

```
   805ea58   <-- br2
    /
b1a22ca   <-- br3, br4
    \
   b31f04a   <-- master (HEAD), br1
```

No *new* commits get added, during this operation: the only thing that changes is that your *current* commit is now `b31f04a` instead of `b1a22ca`, and that the branch label `master` points to `b31f04a`.  (The word `HEAD` moved along with `master` because `HEAD` is "attached to" `master`.  Git shows this as `HEAD -> master` in the `git log` output.)

You can, if you like, run `git merge --no-ff br1` instead.  This forces Git to make a real merge.  However, there are still no changes to find when Git compares `b1a22ca` to itself, so there are no merge conflicts.  If you do this, you get a new commit, with two parents.  You didn't, so I'll just run with the fast-forward:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git merge br1
Updating b1a22ca..b31f04a
Fast-forward
 myfile.txt | 2 +-
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 805ea58 (br2) change line 2
| * b31f04a (HEAD -> master, br1) change line 1
|/  
* b1a22ca (br4, br3) initial
```

#### The second merge is conflicted

When we get to the *second* merge, though, things are different indeed.  This time, the first commit that is shared between `master` (now `b31f04a`) and `br2` (`805ea58`) is `b1a22ca`.  So Git will run:

```
$ git diff --find-renames b1a22ca b31f04a   # what happened on master
diff --git a/myfile.txt b/myfile.txt
index cb3ff6d..8bc2250 100644
--- a/myfile.txt
+++ b/myfile.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-01
+01 one
 02
 03
 04
```

Then Git will run:

```
$ git diff --find-renames b1a22ca 805ea58   # what happened on br2
diff --git a/myfile.txt b/myfile.txt
index cb3ff6d..8bfe146 100644
--- a/myfile.txt
+++ b/myfile.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 01
-02
+02 two
 03
 04
```

Git now goes to *combine* these two changes.  But in Git's eyes, the two changes overlap: the first one touches line 1, and the second touches line 2, and lines 1 and 2 touch each other: that's an overlap.  The two changes are not *identical*, so they cannot be collapsed down to a single change that changes both lines.  The change is therefore a *merge conflict*, which is what you see.

The same thing happens for the remaining merges, once branches `br3` and `br4` have appropriate tip commits.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the questions you're asking in comments, here is some additional explanation.

First you have a starting state with just numbers on each line; we'll call that commit `A`.  That is where `master` points.

```
A <--(master)
            ^HEAD
```

Then you have four branches.  Each branch changes a different line of the code.  We'll keep `HEAD` at `master` in preparation for the merges.

```
A <-(master)
|\         ^HEAD
| B <-(branch1)
|\
| C <-(branch2)
|\
| D <-(branch3)
 \
  E <-(branch4)
```

So you do your first merge

```
git merge branch1
```

Now git is going to look for a merge base between "what you're merging" (`branch1` = `B`) and the `HEAD` (`master` = `A`).  The merge base is typically (and in this case) just the most recent commit reachable from both sides (i.e. from `master` and `branch1`).  Of course `A` is reachable from `master`, and `A` is also reachable from `branch1` because `A` is `B`'s parent.

So we've identified 3 versions.  "ours" (what we're merging changes into) is `A`.  "theirs" (where changes are being merged from) is `B`.  "base" (the merge base between "ours" and "theirs") is `A`, which happens to be the same as "ours".

If we did a full merge, the next step would be to compare "ours" to "base" and also compare "theirs" to "base" to create two patches.  Then we combine those patches.  As long as the patches don't affect the same hunks of code, we can combine them trivially ("we changed hunk A from xxx to yyy; they changed hunk B from zzz to www; so the merged patch does both of those things").  That's roughly how a non-conflicting merge works.  And in this case it's very simple; because "ours" and "base" are the same thing, "we changed nothing"; so the merged patch is equal to the patch between "base" and "theirs".

And in fact, by default git takes a shortcut here.  As soon as it realizes that "ours" is an ancestor of "theirs", it knows it can do a "fast forward" instead of a true merge.  It can just move `master` to where `branch1` is and not merge anything at all.  (You can prevent this by giving the `--no-ff` option to the `merge` command.)

But the point is, even without a fast-forward, this will not conflict because *a conflict by definition means "we" changed the same hunk of code "they" changed*, and in this case "we" didn't change anything.

So now after the fast-forward you have

```
A -- B <-(branch1)(master)
|\                       ^HEAD
| C <-(branch2)
|\
| D <-(branch3)
 \
  E <-(branch4)
```

Notice that `master` is *no longer* an ancestor of `C`, `D`, or `E`; the first merge moved `master` to a commit unreachable from those other branches.  This would be true of a true merge as well; in that case `master` would've moved to a new "merge commit".  Because of the fast-forward, it just moved to `B`, but the effect is the same.

So now you say

```
git merge branch2
```

When we look for a merge base between "ours" (`master` = `B`) and "theirs" (`branch2` = `C`) we'll find `A`.  So again base is `A`, but this time "our changes" are "line 1 changed from '01' to '01 one'".  "Their changes" are "line 2 changed from '02' to '02 two'".

Since the conditions for a fast-forward are not met, we must do the full merge using those two patches.  And you might think "I can combine those patches without conflict" resulting in "line 1 changed from '01' to '01 one' and line 2 changed frmo '02' to '02 two'".  If patches were compared strictly line-by-line, that would be true; but they aren't.

There's a reason they aren't.  The purpose of git is to maintain versions of program source code.  The odds are the code on line 1 is related to the code on line 2.  If changes aren't separated by a respectable distance (no, I don't know what that distance is[1]), they are considered to affect the same hunk.

So rather than assume that these changes are independently correct and don't interfere with one another, git flags it as a conflict and asks you to decide what the final result should be.  Even if you ended up having to needlessly resolve 100 such conflicts, the cost would still be lower than one instance where git assumes it knows what to do and is wrong.

And the analysis for the 3rd and 4th merges will be the same; in each case you have two patches that affect the same hunk of code, so manual intervention is desired.

Now, if you happen to be source controlling some special type of file where you are highly confident (actually, probably you should have to be *absolutely sure*) that changes to one line are independent from changes to the next line, then you *could* write your own merge driver.  It's not trivial, keeping in mind that you have to know what to do when lines are added, when lines are removed, when two versions of the file have deviated much more wildly than what you've shown in your example, etc.

The odds are it's better just to accept that sometimes you have to resolve a conflict.  If you want do compose "toy" tests that simulate non-conflicting merges, the easiest way is to have each branch change a different file; but within a file, changes just can't be too close together or conflicts are going to happen.

---

[1] **UPDATE FROM COMMENTS** - According to torek, having even one intervening line that nobody changed is sufficient.  I didn't think that was correct, but as a rule if torek tells me something I think is wrong, I run another test; and based on that test, I would agree with him.  So in fact it seems you *could* merge `branch1` and `branch3` without conflict, for example.

Comment: A great answer, with some nice insight into how git merges.

Comment: The "distance" required, to make diff hunks apply, is just one line. A hunk "touches" another hunk if they share an edge or any actual content, with "start of file" and "end of file" acting as edges as well.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a method to achieve this scenario without getting merge conflicts?

tl;dr: No.

Merge finds (and in some cases Git's merge will actually construct) the common base and compares diffs from that base to each branch tip.  Any difference in changes to overlapping ranges constitutes a conflict.

Nobody's ever found a way to resolve those overlaps automatically that works.  We've got vast quantities of existing history to work with¸so you can try any method you come up with on the merges in linux or vim or libreoffice or git itself, or what have you, it wouldn't be the first time everybody who's ever looked at a problem missed something, but I'd bet an awful lot on the "can't be done" answer.

The cost of a bad automerge is very high, it's the "pain" in the pain/gain metric.  The gain is simply convenience: many conflicts, like yours, are easy for humans to resolve correctly.  Get good with the tools, easy cases take seconds.  So Git's properly cautious.

Comment: so, why the first merge succeeds?

Comment: You can see the diffs git was looking at with `git diff $mergecommit^1 $mergecommit^2` after the merge.  I suspect the first merge was just merging branch1 into master, with no changes on master at all. Otherwise, I'd say it was a merge of changes separated by enough that the hunks don't overlap.

Comment: ah: your first merge was a fastforward: no merging at all¸ `git merge branch1` just moved the `master` label.

Comment: What @jhill says is true, but even if it *weren't* implemented as a fast-forward the first merge wouldn't conflict because there are no changes on the "ours" side of the merge, and a conflict requires changes on both sides.

Comment: Yeah, my second comment should have pointed out that I made it only because the diff wouldn't work, as there's no second parent at all.

Answer (score 1):

what I found helpful is after branch 1 & 2 are merged to master, checkout to branch 3 and pull from the master and resolve the conflict then push to master, then branch 4 can pull from master all resolved conflicts and merge then push to master.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a method to achieve this scenario without getting merge conflicts?

No (as explained in other answers), but it is possible with the right tooling to have them automatically resolved.

The following builds on all the commands in [Torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996263/23118).

```
$ git merge br2
Auto-merging myfile.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in myfile.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")
  (use "git merge --abort" to abort the merge)

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:   myfile.txt

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
$ git ls-files -u
100644 cb3ff6d73dab0ac586b87f6c5f222e37b85dd32d 1       myfile.txt
100644 8bc2250b70fd06d951fd6ae1ea7ebf0b421ce2e3 2       myfile.txt
100644 8bfe14645e97d71dd4036b5a51d73e29020cba55 3       myfile.txt
$
```

So merging br2 results in a conflict (and you can inspect which versions that are involved with `ls-files`).

Git's internal merge handling fails when two lines next to each other are modified while if using [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) to do the merging instead it will not (which is usually what you want but there is a higher risk of this being incorrect than for lines further apart, so there is a trade off).

Using KDiff3 is simple with the mergetool command;

```
$ git config merge.tool kdiff3
$ git mergetool
Merging:
myfile.txt

Normal merge conflict for 'myfile.txt':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
$ git status
On branch master
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   myfile.txt

Untracked files:
$ ..." to include in what will be committed)

        myfile.txt.orig

$ rm myfile.txt.orig
$ git diff --cached
diff --git a/myfile.txt b/myfile.txt
index 8bc2250..73e9fe0 100644
--- a/myfile.txt
+++ b/myfile.txt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 01 one
-02
+02 two
 03
 04
$
```

KDiff3 is a [graphical 3-way merge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117210/23118) program, but in this case when it resolved things automatically it did not display a window. If there were conflicts that had to be resolved manually it would have.